# How to add rel attribute to each event in FullCalendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have this

```js
$('a.fc-event').each(function() {
   $(this).attr('rel', 'shadowbox');
});
```

after my FullCalendar code, and it works great for the initial page loaded of the calendar. However when you switch to a different month or view, the rel attribute I set is then absent. I need to render that rel="shadowbox" either from FC so it's loaded with every event link everywhere or re-set it again with every view change. How do I do this? Please help, thanks.

Comment: Which `fullCalendar` plugin are you using? (version)

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `eventAfterAllRender` callback,  this callback is called once an entire view + events has been rendered. See [here](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventAfterAllRender/) for more details.

So your code will look something like:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    //... whatever code you already have
    eventAfterAllRender: function (view) {
        //your code here
        $('a.fc-event').each(function() {
            $(this).attr('rel', 'shadowbox');
        });
    }
});
```

You could also look into the `eventRender` callback ([see here](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/)) if you want to do styling per event. (but that is up to you).